# Change text size from prompt using an Android spinner

Tags: android, text, spinner

I have a spinner with a custom text view like in the code below:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:gravity="center_vertical">

</TextView>
```

My problem is that the Text Size of 16sp is applied to the selected item (the text from prompt) too and it's too large for the spinner (it doesn't fit the spinner) and if I change the textSize to 11sp then the items on the list will be too small. How can I change the size only for the selected item?

Comment: If i understand well your question, you want that items in the list have 16sp size but selected item 11sp. Is it right ?

Comment: yes :) the selected item, the one that will be set on the spinner should be smaller in my case

Comment: So it seems that the we can't change the size of the text from prompt after all. Anyway, I made a button and a dialog to simulate the spinner as you suggested and it's working, but I think it's absurd to not be able to handle the text size of the spinner easier and to be forced to simulate a spinner... But thank you very much for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe you can modify textsize in setOnItemClickListener, by the way you can simply create a button and, clicking on it, show a dialog with a list of element so you emulate spinner behavior. In this way you can customize button text size and list as you want